# Java Guitar Hero with Midi

Tags: java, audio, midi, guitar

I'm creating a fake GH with Midi files.
It should load the guitar tracks and save it somewhere. Then play it in specific intervals.

But I've no idea how to get the guitar tracks and the notes.
Additionally, I need to play the notes simultaneous with the sound which is currently played.

EDIT: specific:
1) I have to load a midi file (lets say metallica, something with guitars)
2) I want to get the guitar tracks and choose one of them. Or simply choose the first guitar. Well, it doesn't matter.
3) Here comes the point: The program should get the strings (E, A, D, G, b, e) in specific intervals. e.g. get the string of the guitar at 1:21. (I think they should be stored in a list and then calculate the note at that time)

[Java midi note to string mapping via octave of a note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352615/java-midi-note-to-string-mapping-via-octave-of-a-note)
This one I already found, but it wasn't the kind of code I was looking for.

So please help me!
I need it for school purposes.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why dont you ask to your teachers. as you required it for school

Comment: I already did! They don't know midi very well.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here.  Perhaps you could update your question and reframe it a bit, what specific programming issues are you having?  Or are you struggling more with design/architecture?